# Passing dynamic arguments into heroku scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, scheduled-tasks, cleardb

I'm trying to update my database by calling a cisco's cmx api.

But since I'm using free version of cleardb, there is an hourly limit of 3600 insertions.

Therefore I need to create a task with dynamic variables. I have the following information;

```
"totalPages":180,
"currentPage":1,
"pageSize":3600,
"nextResourceURI":"https://10.10.20.150/api/contextaware/v1/location/history/clients/?page=2&pageSize=3600"
```

So I want to create a task with those variables and automatically change the nextResourceURI.

My solution was to write to a database and retrieve the currentPage value from there, but I don't think it's an efficient and good solutions.

That would be great if you can help me,

Thanks!